# Throw new error when instantiation a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple JavaScript "class" with the help of a function. However, I want to validate if the input data is correct before setting the values. If the data is not correct, I want to throw a new Error. This is what I came up with:

```
function Testing(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arg1 !== '' && arg2 !== '') {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Data is empty!');
  }
}
```

Is this allowed in JavaScript? What would be a better solution?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: So the data is invalid only if both the arguments are empty?

Comment: This is perfectly fine. You can look at the approaches here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw. All the examples use `if-else` to throw the error.

Comment: What would make you think it would not be allowed in JS? What would make you think that using `throw` to report a fatal error condition is not a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Throwing on construction of the object is good, because it ensures the consistency of its internals.

Comparatively, if you decided to e.g. use a special `.invalid` field, the user could ignore the fact that the creation did, in fact, fail.